# How to save dynamic enum value in the database in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, enums

i am developing an application in mvc3...
and i am having hell of time dealing with ENUM.

I have made an enum class:

Hobby.cs

```
    public enum Hobby
    {
    [Display(Name = "Dancing")]
    Dancing = 1
    ,
    [Display(Name = "Singing")]
    Singing = 2
    ,
    [Display(Name = "Painting")]
    Painting = 3
    ,
    [Display(Name = "Cooking")]
    Cooking = 4
    ,
    [Display(Name = "Photography")]
    Photography = 5

    }
```

I have used Hobby class as a type in another class called HobbyDetail.cs

```
 public class HobbyDetail
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int HobbyDetailId { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(Hobby), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources),        ErrorMessageResourceName = "HobbyRequired")]
    [Display(Name = "lblHobby", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public virtual Hobby Hobby { get; set; }

    public virtual string StudyMedium { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Fees { get; set; }
    public virtual char ForWhom { get; set; }
    public virtual Boolean InclusiveStudyMaterial { get; set; }
    public virtual int AgeFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual int AgeTo { get; set; }
    public virtual string HobbyInfo { get; set; }

}
```

Then further i have made an object of the above class in another class

named Person.cs as

```
  public virtual HobbyDetail Hobby { get; set; }
```

I have inserted the following code inside my controller:

```
 public viewResult(Person person)
 {


 PersonalProfileService personalProfileService = new PersonalProfileService();

 person.Hobby.Hobby = Hobby.Dancing;
 personalProfileService.SaveBasicProfileWithHobby(person);

 }
```

I'm using NHibernate and SaveBasicProfileWithHobby() is the method of service class.. they are working fine......

I am able to store the static value in the database but i am not able to save dynamic value to my database whatevr the user has selected from the dropdown created with the help of enum.
Suggest me the code of lines to be placed inside the controller so that this will help me store the dynamic enum value in database.
Please..

Comment: just type cast it to int before saving.

Comment: @Sachin hi can u show me how to do that..please

Comment: assuming you are saving the object using LINQ (apologies for bad formatting)-
public void SavePerson(Person person){
using (DBContext dbContext = new DbContext()){
dbPerson.Hobby = (int)person.Hobby;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
}

Comment: @Sachin hi i tried watu said but itstill does not work...i have updated my code...pls have a look ..... maybe this will help you to solve my problem....

Comment: this may be beacuse either dbperson.Hobby or person.Hobby must be null and your are trying to get to .Hobby of a null object, hence the error

Comment: @Yasser Hi i have updated my code plzz have a look at it...i hav been able to resolve it a bit but nt completely!! please help me

Answer (score 1):

HobbyDetail.cs:

```
public short HobbyId {get; set;}
```

and get value like:

```
    public Hobby Hobby
    {
        get
        {
            return (Hobby)HobbyId;
        }
        set
        {
            HobbyId = (byte)Hobby;
        }
    }
```

and your enum can look like this:

```
public enum Hobby : byte
{
    Dancing = 1,
    Singing = 2
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `set { HobbyId = (byte)value; }` ?